# vaadin combobox in polymer 3

Tags: combobox, vaadin14, polymer-3.x

I have following code to use vaadin combo box in polymer 3, but itis not working.

```
<vaadin-combo-box id ="select" placeholder="Please select">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item">
  <option value$="{{item.id}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.type}}</option>
</vaadin-combo-box>
```

I understand, it has to do with  and , else if I just use exact values in items, it works

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `template` with `dom-repeat`. There is internal logic that populates the popup with `vaadin-item`'s based on items property (note, it does not use `option`), so it should be enough if you do

```
<vaadin-combo-box
  label="Type"
  placeholder="Please select"
  item-label-path="type"
  item-value-path="id"
  items="{{this.items}}"
></vaadin-combo-box>
```

Comment: thanks. Though there are some items, which are just headers and I want them to be disabled. How can I do that